# WebDriver Selenium Execute_Script Downloading a .Tmp File

Tags: python

I was running into "elementnotclickable" exceptions so I did research on here and found that using execute_script("arguments[0].click(); could solve the issue. I am downloading a PDF using the run_report variable. When I use the execute_script it downloads a .tmp file instead of a .pdf. Can something be corrupting it when its being executed?

```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,
                               executable_path=r'C:\name\drivers\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get('website')
        for row in rows:
            col2 = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[6]
            if col2 in filename_l:
                col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[0].click()
                run_report = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl07_ctlReportRender_ctl01_btnRun"]')
                browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", run_report)
                col3 = WebDriverWait(row, 300).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "td"))).click()
                logging.info(col2.text + " was downloaded.")
                print(col2.text + " was downloaded")
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of said .tmp file? If you rename said file to .pdf, does it open in your PDF reader?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I just tried it and it said file could be damage or corrupt. When i take away the execute_script it will download a good pdf.

Comment: So, what's in the .tmp file? Have you tried opening it with a text editor? Perhaps you're getting an error and the server replied with an HTML file and the error details are within.